# API request isn't giving a response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to use (https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/) to populate a table in my ios app, but there isn't any data displaying. I have tried my api keys and the url a bunch of times so I don't think its that. Structure of the json file

Dev-category school

Name String
The institution’s name (INSTNM), as reported in IPEDS.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let URLStr = "https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?fields=school.name"

    var resultArray = [Users]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
     var searchCollege = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         tableView.dataSource = self
         tableView.delegate = self
         callAPI()


            }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
           super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }

func callAPI() {
        let key = "key redacted"
        //let url = URL(string:"\(URLStr)?api_key=\(key)")
        let url = URL(string:"\(URLStr)&api_key=\(key)")
        print(url)
        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers:[:]).responseJSON {(response) in
            if let responseObj = response.value as? [[String: Any]]{
                self.resultArray = self.parseJSON(userData: responseObj)
                print("response here", response)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }

}
func parseJSON(userData: [[String:Any]])-> [Users] {
    var userArr = [Users]()
    for obj in userData {
        do { let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Users.self, from: data)
            userArr.append(decodedData)
            }

    catch {

        }
    }
        return userArr
    }
}
```

userModal.swift

```
mport Foundation
struct Users: Codable {
    let userSchool_name: String?
}
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userSchool_name = "school.name"
}
```

I have tried to print out the response and the different objects but nothing prints out. I have a function below that displays it in the app, but I don't think that is the problem.

json output

```
SUCCESS: {
    metadata =     {
        page = 0;
        "per_page" = 20;
        total = 7112;
    };
    results =     (
                {
            "school.name" = "West Michigan College of Barbering and Beauty";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Georgia College & State University";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Georgia Southern University";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Clayton  State University";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Andrew College";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Columbus Technical College";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Georgia Northwestern Technical College";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Atlanta Metropolitan State College";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Clark Atlanta University";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Augustana College";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Miami Ad School at Portfolio Center";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Tricoci University of Beauty Culture-Urbana";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "University of Hawaii at Manoa";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Aveda Institute-Twin Falls";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Cameo Beauty Academy";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Truett McConnell University";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Cannella School of Hair Design-Chicago";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "Valdosta State University";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "American Academy of Art";
        },
                {
            "school.name" = "City Colleges of Chicago-Kennedy-King College";
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Does it print the `url`?

Comment: have you tried printing the response before the condition `if let responseObj = response.value as? [[String: Any]]`

Comment: @Rob the url does print out, but thank you

Comment: @jenna Ok, so does it `parseJSON` successfully?

Comment: @Joshua it does print before the ```if let responseObj = response.value as? [[String: Any]]```  so I don't think it is successfully doing parseJSON @Rob

Comment: @jenna the expected response is not what it's actually returning. you might need to investigate on what the actual structure is then check the parsing of data

Comment: `print(error)` inside your `catch`, don't just throw it away.  It will provide insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried to do that but nothing printed out...

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `parseJSON` and step through to see what is happening

Comment: @Paulw11 so as soon as it goes to ```var userArr = [User]() ``` it jumps to line ```Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: ```

Comment: @jenna Here in your code please don't convert into URL and pass only string in Alamofire.request, I have tried your code and i am getting nil response and you have used this code `if let responseObj = response.value as? [[String: Any]]`. your response is nil so because of optional it skip this code.

Comment: @jenna, can you share your `Users` model and `response` of the API that you get. Looks like the issue is with Decoder and model classes

Comment: Okay I got this error: ```Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fff87c524b0) to 'NSArray' (0x7fff87c51fb0).
2020-02-24 09:19:47.419076-0500 AlphaApplication[6636:422871] Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fff87c524b0) to 'NSArray' (0x7fff87c51fb0).``` @Paulw11 @Tushar Moradiya

Comment: So it seems that you have a dictionary when your code says that is should have an array.  You need to check the JSON that is being returned and make sure that your struct matches

Comment: @Paulw11 I put in my json data, how should I format it? I am a little confused

Comment: `let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data); userArr = decodedData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all delete `parseJSON`, it makes no sense to convert the JSON to an array, then back to JSON and then to a struct with `JSONDecoder`

```
func parseJSON(userData: [[String:Any]])-> [Users] {
var userArr = [Users]()
for obj in userData {
    do { let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Users.self, from: data)
        userArr.append(decodedData)
        }

catch {

    }
}
    return userArr
}
}
```

Then you have to add a struct for the root object

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let results : [Users]
}

struct Users: Codable {
    let userSchool_name: String?

     private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userSchool_name = "school.name"
     }
}
```

And replace the Alamofire part with

```
   Alamofire.request(url!).responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    self.resultArray = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data).results
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
            }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
        }
    }
```

It receives `Data` rather than a decoded array and handles all errors.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I got this error, typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Thank you-> but its giving the value as a nil,  print(self.resultArray) gives   Application.Users(userSchool_name: nil), but for the right amount of schools

Comment: The `CodingKeys` enum must be inside the `Users` struct and you might declare `userSchool_name` non-optional and *lowerCamelCased*.